# ImageMagick, stack 100 pictures on each other

Tags: imagemagick

I have 300 small pictures. Each picture is a black background and a red dot. I want to add all these pictures together so that all dots form a line.

I've tried:

```
magick *.jpg images.gif
```

and it works but instead of a GIF I just want a picture of the line created.

Comment: You say your command works, so what is wrong with the line?

Comment: @harrymc “I want to add all these pictures together so that all dots form a line.” and then “…and it works but instead of a GIF I just want a picture of the line created.” Meaning, as a GIF I assume it is creating an animated GIF? And the original poster just wants one large composite image.

Comment: @user1098668: Are the GIFs animated? What is the result of running your above command?

Answer (score 1):

```
magick composite -compose plus image1.jpg image2.jpg imagecomposite.jpg
```

That should work for two images.  You can use your imagination for the rest.  Given each batch of pixels will go through about 7 operations at least, you might consider saving to an uncompressed format (like TIFF for bmp) for intermediate steps.

Comment: So this would work as well, correct? Asking because the original poster was using a wildcard in their example: `magick composite -compose plus magick *.jpg`

Comment: I don't use the tool often enough to know if that would work.  I just know photo editing well enough to know what to look for.  I don't think globbing works in this case. As far as I can tell from the documentation composite only works on 2 input files.  So at least 99 operations would be required to composite 100 images.

Answer (score -1):

So ImageMagick is being deprecated… with CentOS 7.7 and 8.

You would want to use GraphicsMagick via:

```
gm <imagemagick command>
```

It’s real simple replacing ImageMagick with GraphicsMagick, and I think the command you want is either `composite` making use of mask-image, or `montage`.

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html

Comment: GraphicsMagick is originally derived from ImageMagick 5.5.2 as of November 2002 but has been completely independent of the ImageMagick project since then. Since the fork from ImageMagick many improvements have been made (see NEWS) by many authors using an open development model but without breaking the API or utilities operation.

Comment: Since GraphicsMagick is more stable, more time has been spent optimizing and debugging its code.

Comment: GraphicsMagick is usually faster than ImageMagick. The baseline execution overhead for simple commands is much lower, and GraphicsMagick is also more efficient at dealing with large images

Comment: In May 2016, it was reported that ImageMagick had a vulnerability through which an attacker can execute arbitrary code on servers that use the application to edit user-uploaded images.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick

Comment: None of your points have anything to do with the core question. Also, when you state, “you deleted out the rest of my answer stating gm composite and montage” this is an utter falsehood. My edits were purely formatting. And your sentence on `composite` and `montage` is still intact. Don’t believe me? [Check the edit history](https://superuser.com/posts/1490017/revisions); utterly no deletion of content.

Comment: @ron did you literally just copy/paste talking points from the project home page you linked?

Comment: Spam perhaps? Is Ron a dev of the product he suggests.

Comment: **whoever modified and deleted 90% of the content of my answer leaving just what is there should not be a moderator**

Comment: manipulative ahole!

Comment: > @ron did you literally just copy/paste talking points from the project home page you linked?  yeah, you asked what graphicsmagick had to do with an imagemagick question and that's exactly what i provided.  If you are going to play games you can delete my account